# CSS and direct descendants?

Tags: css

I'm trying to target direct descendants. I want direct descendants of the first ol to be lowercase but nested ol inside the li should not have this style applied, but in the example below, it is getting applied. Why?

How can I nest several direct descendants?

CSS:

```
nav > ol > li {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
nav > ol > li > ol > li {
  /* do not apply any text transform */
}
```

Markup:

```
<nav>
    <ol>
       <li>
           <ol>
               <li></li>
           </ol>
       </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why would someone edit the sass to css? I want to know the answer in sass.

Comment: What does your compiled css look like? If you don't have any styling then the compiled css won't include anything for the innermost `>li{`

Comment: Unless you have a problem getting Sass to compile to the desired CSS, this is not a Sass problem.  Do not use the Sass tag or post Sass code unless the problem is specific to solving a problem in Sass.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770625/text-transform-cannot-change-be-overwritten-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) `&`

```
nav{
    &>ol{
        &>li{
            text-transform: lowercase;
            &>ol{
                &>li{
                     //do not apply any text transform
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as what the OP already has.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP edited his question ;)

Comment: Actually... you edited the question...

Comment: Yes, and I don't believe you actually solved the problem.  The OP's original Sass and what you posted compile to the exact same CSS.  This isn't a Sass problem.

Comment: The OP had a SASS question. The resulting CSS for the SASS that I provided is indeed different.

Comment: No, it's not.  [Code posted by the OP](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9032df337f6d3f075ba8) vs [code posted by you](http://sassmeister.com/gist/5a89247dd76ced0a68df).  The output is identical.

Comment: Ah. I'm sorry, I was wrong.